# Moving Home Partition?

Tags: 13.04

I followed the directions exactly as they are layed out here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

My home is moved but I cannot access anything in it. All folders have a lock on them and when I try to access any of them I am told:

This location could not be displayed.
You do not have the neccessary permissions to view the contents of "Name of Folder"

Help, please!!

If nothing else could someone point me in the direction of how to restore my original Home. I have not deleted the old_home that was created following the steps in the link above.

Comment: Everything shows as root except for the 2 folders I can get into. I am trying to now figure out what command line to run to change the permisions from root to danny. Got it....I changed the ownership to me by running "sudo chown -R danny /home". Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!!!

Answer (score 0):

Run `ls -l` to see how the permissions are set for the folder. If you have sudo priveleges, can you access the directory as root? If so then you just need to change the priveleges of the folder using some combination of `sudo chown` and `sudo chmod`. Read the man pages for `chown` and `chmod` for some information.